# Enzootic vs Epizootic?

Tags: microbiology, terminology, epidemiology

I'm studying microbiology and I see these words - *epizootic* and *enzootic*, often but there are no clear explanations for them online. Can someone help please?

Comment: Analogous to endemic and epidemic.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that before! Could you please put that as an answer so I can credit you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[*Enzootic*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/enzootic) and *[epizootic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/epizootic)* are analogous to *endemic* and *epidemic*, respectively.

*Enzootic* means something that affects a population of non-human animals  in a limited spatio-temporal region whereas *epizootic* is relatively more widespread.

*Endemic* and *epidemic* are more general terms and do not, technically, apply to only humans.